# Add nested array to Laravel request

Tags: arrays, laravel, request

I am trying to add to a nested array in a request in my controller. At the moment, my request looks like this:

```
+request: ParameterBag {#43 ▼
#parameters: array:3 [▼
"_token" => "*****"
"my-event" => array:26 [▼
"title" => "my new event"
"start-date" => "2019-05-01"
 .....
```

I would like to add to this request in the "my-event" array, e.g. "event-approved" with a value of 0.

I can see that you can add to a request like so:

```
$request->request->add(['my-key' => 'value']);
```

But I am unsure on how to do this for a nested array. I would want something like:

```
$request->request->add(['my-event']['event-approved'] = '0');
```

But I am getting the error:

> Cannot use temporary expression in write context

Comment: `['my-event']['event-approved'] = '0'` is not a valid parameter you can use in `$request->request->add()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better and faster approach is:

```
$event = $request->get('my-event');
$event['event-approved'] = "0";
$request->request->add(['my-event'=>$event]);
```

**NOTE** that it will NOT override any existing fields of `my-event` array except only set the `event-approved` field.

Or if you want a one-liner try:

```
$request->request->add(['my-event'=>array_merge($request->get('my-event'),['event-approved'=>"0"])]);
```

There is no other short-hand method for this kind of manipulation

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way of doing this but there may be a more efficient way of doing this:

```
$requestData = $request->all();
$requestData['my-event']['event-approved'] = "0";

$request->merge($requestData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
  $event = array_merge($request->request->get('my-event'), ['event-approved' => 0]
  $request->request->add(['my-event' => $event]);
```

Comment: `$value = ['my-event']['event-approved'] = '0';` is INVALID php syntax!!

Comment: this is a copy of my own answer!!  Please